# Simple question about an if block in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rhtml

I am trying to tell ruby to not run a block of html and ruby if no active record exists in the database. Below is the code I was trying to run conditions on.

```
<% if @statemant.comments.exists?() do %>  
<div id="comments">  
<h2>Comments</h2>  
<%= render :partial => @statemant.comments %>  
</div>  
<% end %>
```

Comment: What's the problem, is it just not displaying the render?

Comment: It appears to not be ending the do statement.

Comment: The render :partial line looks suspect. Is that working for you?

Comment: Yes that works fine and I have not had any problems with my syntax. Do you render your partials a different way?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to get rid of the `do` from your `if` statement (you can optionally replace it with `then`). `do` is used for blocks. `if` isn't a function, so it doesn't take a block.

Comment: Thank you. That did it. I should have known if doesn't require a do statement.

Comment: For reference, `then` is required if the condition precedes the block on the same line.

Comment: @EmFi Can you give an example please? Thanks.